Query pubkeys that reference lookup table
Is there a way, and if so how would one go about querying for all pubkeys that reference a specific lookup table for a transaction?
Ex: https://solscan.io/tx/4HqK7AQeaJfXdrwmasAePpb61EBGchQyTG8LsaZUNCkKXu3zKR6YffaTvvX6wWv9G84Qa7M4FJKSeE2zrPmV6h2Z
For this transaction, it references Address lookup table: 3ueupgmdHHPkW3p9in42itGUTHkLW97XzXNiXUPn3RPs
I’m not looking for all pubkeys that are in this lookup table, but for all pubkeys or even tx signatures that reference this LUT
thanks!

You should be able to use the getSignaturesForAddress RPC endpoint and provide the LUT address. That way, you'll get all transaction signatures that reference the LUT. After that, you can call getTransaction for each one to learn more about the transaction
More information at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getsignaturesforaddress and https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction
